# var_dump of an int shows UNKNOWN:0

Tags: php

I've found something I've never seen before in PHP. My script aborts with the error:

> Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in ... on line 41

The error message refers to the following statement:

```
if($this->lastAction + 7200 <= time()) {
}
```

When I var_dump the `$this->lastAction` before the operation in my script I get the output:

```
UNKNOWN:0
```

I've never seen that before. And I can't imagine where this value is assigned to my variable or under what condition this happens.

Has anyone a hint or an explanation where this "value" is coming from?

**UPDATE 1**

I found out that if I run the same setup on a env with PHP 5.3 I get instead the error:

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int ... on line 41

But I never ever assign a `stdClass` instance to this variable.

**UPDATE 2**

Problem also exists in PHP `5.5.19` with the same error as in version `5.4.28`.

---

**AuthHandler.php**

```
abstract class AuthHandler
{
    protected $lastAction;

    public function __construct()
    {
         $this->lastAction = isset($_SESSION['last_action']) ? $_SESSION['last_action'] : time();

         if($this->lastAction + 7200 <= time()) {
             $this->logout();
         }

         $this->lastAction = time();
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        session_destroy();
        session_regenerate_id();

        $this->lastAction = null;
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        $_SESSION['last_action'] = $this->lastAction;
    }
}
```

**DBAuthHandler.php**

```
class DBAuthHandler extends AuthHandler
{
    // other stuff here
}
```

Comment: What type is `$this`?

Comment: can you output the type of `$this->lastAction` using [gettype()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php).

Comment: What is your php version?

Comment: PHP version is `5.4.28` and as `var_dump()` indicates with `UNKNOWN:0` I get `unknown type` with `getttype()` function. `$this` is an own class instance I created.

Comment: It looks like a bug. Could you create minimal reproducible code?

Comment: I'll try to do that but it's very difficult because it's an abstract class which my class is based on and it works in most cases. Just in a specific script where I use this class this happens. Will be very difficult to reproduce this on an abstract and simple code sample I guess. The problem is I nowhere find any hint about `UNKNOWN:0` with googling it.

Comment: You could search for occurring  of this value on [bugs.php.net](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%22UNKNOWN%3A0%22+site%3Abugs.php.net)

Comment: Have you tried `self::$lastAction`?

Comment: @RápliAndrás Well `$lastAction` is not a static class property. It's defined with `protected $lastAction` and used in a none static class method.

Comment: Okay. I guess, then we'd need more info about this class to further investigate.

Comment: Aren't you getting something like `Warning: Abstract class cannot be instantiated`?

Comment: @RápliAndrás Nope I don't instanciate the abstract class. I Instantiate a class which inherts from the abstract class. I'll put a sample code above in a minute.

Comment: **Added sample code of my class definitions**

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is not a definitive answer but might shed some light into the issue.

Checking PHP Source, ***"unknown type"*** is the default case in the [**gettype function**](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/1b4fd5825a820873e4ed0f326bcb890e660dc39c/ext/standard/type.c#L85). The same is valid for [**var_dump function**](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/77f172725a37c8ddee750bf6970529a1570fbc86/ext/standard/var.c#L202).

So, basically, when a variable isn't *NULL*, *boolean*, *integer*, *double*, *string*, *array*, *object* or *resource* then it's of ***unknown type***.

I've seen this happen when a pointer becomes invalid.

```
$handle = fopen('file.txt','r');
echo gettype($handle); // resource
fclose($handle);
echo gettype($handle); // unknown
```

---

Since [time()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) always returns an integer (or, at least, it should) then the problem must lie with `$_SESSION['last_action']`.

Even using several methods to destroy `$_SESSION`, I couldn't reproduce your issue.

Maybe it will help if you backtrace `$_SESSION['last_action']`, checking its value periodically.

Comment: Yes you're right so far. I had two instances of the class at the same time which somehow created a mess in the session var you mentioned above. In PHP 5.4 and 5.5 I had a `stdClass` object in this var I never assigned to a session but used somewhere in the script runtime. In PHP 5.3 I had this `UNKNOWN:0`. So it seems a bug in PHP which somehow addresses wrong memory I guess. However I worked around this issue so that I only have one class instance at once now and got it working.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided perfectly works for me. The returned object is

```
object(App\Http\Controllers\DBAuthHandler)#141 (1) { ["lastAction":protected]=> int(1416817485) }
```

So the problem will be in the method that tries to set `$_SESSION['last_action']`.

Comment: As I said: It work's in all cases except in one script where I use this object. And it's a very basic usage of OO so I guess it's really a bug in the PHP core somehow.

Comment: That's sad to hear. Good luck with refactoring then